# Executing multiple case using PHP switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have to execute multiple set of instructions based upon a value, for example.

```
$value = 'AA';
switch ($value) {
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals  1";
    continue;
    case 'BB':
        echo "value equals 2";
    continue;
    case 'CC' || 'AA':
        echo "value equals 3";
    break;
}
```

What i am expecting from the above code is it should execute multiple cases based upon the values passed, the variable $value contains `AA` as the value so hence i am expecting it to execute both

`case 'AA'` and
`case 'CC' || 'AA'`

so it should print out `value equals  1 value equals 3` however it does not execute it that way i am getting only `value equals 1` as output. and if i remove `continue` from the statement it executes all three `cases` which is logically wrong.  does the PHP's switch statement support multiple cases to be executed based on a single value? is there any workaround for this?

thank you..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a `break` is missing then a `switch` statement enables falling through to the next condition:

```
$value = 'AA';
switch ($value) {
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals  1"; // this case has no break, enables fallthrough
    case 'CC':
        echo "value equals 3"; // this one executes for both AA and CC
    break;
    case 'BB':
        echo "value equals 2";
    break;
}
```

Comment: oh ok, so there is no way switch statement supports executing multiple cases based upon the condition.? if it allows fallthrough if it finds no break then isn't it supposed to check the next case condition and based upon it allow or jumpthough another condition?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: Multiple cases **can be executed**, by arranging the fallthrough structure and conditions accordingly. Actually my first example was a bit off, try the current one - it executes multiple cases for `AA`.

Comment: What exactly is the difference in behaviour now? It looks like it should the same if the first case falls through and the next case checks only `CC`. Isn't the condition completely ignored on a fall through?

Comment: yes kapep. this will not work unless i structure the value accordingly. for example if the value is passed out of context it will still execute the middle case. try assigning `DD` to `$value` which is out of context and it will execute the middle case. whereas i expect the code not to run at all if the value passed is out of context.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: Actually @kapep unwittingly pointed out a bug which my previous update introduced. `||`-ing two non-zero literals always results `true`, hence it matches every non-zero `$value`. Which makes the expression meaningless, one could replace `case 'AA' || 'CC'` with `case true` and have identical behaviour. At any rate, I rolled back the previous change. Fallthrough multiple execution depends only on the **ordering of breakless cases**. Value expressions serve only as initial entry points.

Comment: @Saul: thanks for the heads up, you're right about the case behavior. Upped :)

Answer (score 3):

The `switch` statement needs literals in the case blocks. Use an `if` statements instead.

You can use other sorts of loop to `iterate` through the value, and then use `IF`'s for comparison. Doing comparison/condition checking isn't possible in the `switch` cases.

One way to accomplish what you want to do is like this (note IF is being used):

```
$value = 'AA';
switch($value)
{
    case ('AA'):
        echo "value equals 1<br />";
    case ('BB'):
        if ($value == 'BB'){
            echo "value equals 2<br />";
        }
    case (('AA') || ('CC')):
        echo "value equals 3<br />";
        break;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
value equals 1
value equals 3
```

NOTE:- the above solution isn't right although its outputting what you need its not the right solution and if possible i would recommend avoiding. Your needs can easily be fixed using non-switch/case alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The work around is to use a set of `if` and `else if` statements. Conditions in `case` statements are not evaluated.

```
if($value == 'AA') {
    echo "value equals 1";
}
else if($value == 'CC') {
    echo "value equals 3";
}
else { //Or else if($value == 'BB') if you might add more at some point
    echo "value equals 2";
}
```

The `continue` (or `break` statement) ends each `case`. If it is omitted, execution will fall through to the next `case` (which is why all three get executed in your case - it falls through all of them, right to the end. If a `continue` or `break` is encountered in a `case` that has been fallen through to, execution will stop there).

Comment: i cannot use if else because code needs to be executed several times based upon value for example Value `AA` may execute condition 1 and 3, or condition 1 and 2 and 3 or any one condition. `if else` will come out once it execute the first one. i guess the only way left out is using multiple `if`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation I see that switch statements can have multiple cases which evaluate true, but not multiple case blocks which evaluate true.

Also, the documentation states that `break;` and `continue;` in the scope of a `switch` are equivalent.

If you leave all `break;` and `continue;` statements out, you'll see that they all print regardless of matching. You'll have to use the less cool if/else/ifelse statements for this conundrum.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: That won't work. I had never seen a repeated case in a switch before, so I tried it thinking it was a cool concept. Unfortunately, it only evaluates the first instance, so it only prints `value equals 1`, but not `value equals 3`.

Comment: sure @Patrick Robert Shea O'Connor . looking fwd for your reply :)

Comment: `continue` in a switch statement doesn't make the switch a loop. Even if it would, without modifing the condition, it would be an endless one.

Comment: @kapep that's what I was saying, that a `break;` and `continue;` in the scope of a `switch` are the same thing, that they both break the `switch` out and end any further processing of statements. A `switch` or for that matter a `if/else` are not loops. `for/while` are loops you can wrap around a `if/else` or `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code like this
When we are checking more than one condition than we need to add conditional statement there.

```
$value = 'AA';
switch ($value) {
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals  1";
    continue;
    case 'BB':
        echo "value equals 2";
    continue;
    case $value == 'CC' || $value=='AA':
        echo "value equals 3";
    break;
}
```

Or you can simply write your code in this format (put two different cases for that)

```
$value = 'AA';
switch ($value) {
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals  1";
    continue;
    case 'BB':
        echo "value equals 2";
    continue;
    case 'CC':
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals 3";
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. 'Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break" ' This is what PHP output for this code. The correct answer is @Saul's answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
$value = 'AA';
switch ($value) {
    case 'AA':
        echo "value equals 1";
        echo "value equals 3";
    break;
    case 'BB':
        echo "value equals 2";
    break;
    case 'CC':
        echo "value equals 3";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, you would not run the third case for `AA`