# Can I use the same case value multiple times in a switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

Can I write a switch statement like this?

```
   switch ($mood) {

    case hungry : 
    case sad : 
    echo 'Eat a chocolate';


    case sad : 
    echo 'Call Up your friend';

    }
```

Is this a good practice?

EDIT : Removed the break statement, based on the comment.

Comment: You can, but it is strange, because you will never get the second `sad` echo...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117499/executing-multiple-case-using-php-switch-statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is technically possible to define multiple cases with the same value, but only the first case will get executed. So it's pretty much useless.

From the [`switch()`](http://php.net/switch) documentation:

> PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement.

Since the first case has a [`break`](http://php.net/break) in it, further cases won't be executed and the code will exit the `switch()` block.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
$var = 'sad';

switch ($var) {
    case 'sad':
        echo 'First';
        break;
    case 'sad':
        echo 'Second';
        break;
}
```

This will output `First`.

If you want to execute multiple statements if a condition is `TRUE`, then add them under the same case, like so:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 'sad':
        echo 'First';
        echo 'Second';
        break;
}
```

Comment: But if there is no break ... !

Comment: I quess it was there, as it is mentioned in original post

Answer (score 0):

This question shown on top for a search, so I wanted to write correct approach. You don't need to write case "sad" multiple times, if it enters to case "sad" it will continue down until "break".

```
 $mood= "sad";
   switch ($mood) {

    case "sad" : 
    echo 'Eat a chocolate';

    case "hungry" : 
    echo 'Call Up your friend';

    }
```

or

```
  $mood= "sad";
    switch ($mood) {

    case "sad" : 
    echo 'Eat a chocolate';

    case "hungry" : 
    echo 'Call Up your friend';
    break;
    }
```

And I don't think it as bad practice because this is cleaner than if else statement.

A good use scenario is handling changes to database according to version of the code/plugin. For example if you have to make some changes according to version of the code on your update call, you can use this approach.

```
  switch ($version) 
    {
      case "1.0":
        // add x field to table a
        // remove y field from table a
      case "1.1":
       // add z field to table b
      case "1.2":
       // create a new table c
      case "1.5":
       // add field m to table c
}
```

So if version is 1.1, the code in 1.1 and below (until latest version) will be executed. So it is cleaner approach than if statements.